# How to load a JcomboBox enum from previous JcomboBox selected item from Enum? JAVA

Tags: java, swing, enums, jcombobox

I have 3 enum classes and my JInternalFrame implements my three jComboBox.

This combos are:

```
jComboBox comboSubGrupos
comboTipoIndustria comboTipoIndustria
cmboTipoIndustria19SubGrupos comboSubGrupoTipoIndustria19
cmboTipoIndustria1SubGrupos comboSubGrupoTipoIndustria1
```

When an index of the comboTipoIndustria is selected, I need my comboSubGrupos to take the values of values of TipoIndustria19SubGrupos.enum.

If another index is selected, I want the comboSubGrupos to take value of TipoIndustria1SubGrupos.enum

```
public enum TipoIndustria {

    PROCESAMIENTO_CONSERVACION_DE_ALIMENTOS_BEBIDAS_TABACO("Procesamiento y Conservacíon de alimentos, bebida y tabaco",
            1),
    INDUSTRIA_FRIGORIFICO("Industria frigorífico", 2), PESCA("Pesca", 3), INDUSTRIA_TEXTIL("Industra Textil", 4),
    INDUSTRIA_CUERO_VESTIMENTA_CALZADO("Industrias del Cuero, Vestimenta y Calzado", 5),
    INDUSTRIA_MADERA_CELULOSA_PAPEL("Industria de la Madera, celulosa y papel", 6),
    INDUSTRIA_QUIMICA_FARMACEUTICA("Industria química, del medicamento, farmacéutica, de combustibles y anexos", 7),
    INDUSTRIA_PRUDCTOS_METALICOS_MAQUINARIA_EQUIPO("Industria de productos metálicos, maquinarias y equipo", 8),
    INDUSTRIA_CONSTRUCCION("Industria de la construcción y actividades complementarias", 9),
    COMERCIO_GENERAL("Comercio en general", 10), COMERCIO_MINORISTA("Comercio minorista de la alimentación", 11),
    COMERCIO_MINORISTA_ALIMENTACION("Hoteles, restoranes y bares", 12),
    HOTELES_RESTORANES_BARES("Transporte y almacenamiento", 13),
    TRANSPORTE_Y_ALMACENAMIENTO("Intermediación financiera, seguros y pensiones", 14),
    INTERMEDIACION_FINANCIERA("Servicios de salud y anexos", 15),
    SERVICIOS_SALUD_ENSENIANZA("Servicios de enseñanza", 16), INDUSTRIA_GRAFICA("Industria gráfica", 17),
    SERVICIOS_CULTURALES("Servicios culturales, de esparcimiento y comunicaciones", 18),
    SERVICIOS_PROFESIONALES("Servicios profesionales, técnicos, especializados y aquellos no incluidos en otros grupos",
            19),
    ENTIDADES_GREMIALES("Entidades gremiales, sociales y deportivas", 20), SERVICIO_DOMESTICO("Servicio doméstico", 21),
    GANADERIA("Ganadería, Agricultura y actividades conexas", 22),
    VINIEDOS_FRUTICULTURA(
            "Viñedos, fruticultura, horticultura, floricultura, criaderos de aves, suinos, apicultura y otras actividades",
            23),
    FORESTACION("Forestación (incluído bosques, montes y turberas)", 24);

    private String texto;
    private double grupo; 

    private TipoIndustria(String texto, double grupo) {
        this.texto = texto;
        this.grupo = grupo;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return this.texto;
    }

    public double getGrupo() {
        return this.grupo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return texto;
    }
}
```

Second enum

```
public enum TipoIndustria19SubGrupos {

    DESPACHANTE_ADUANA("Despachantes de Aduana",1),
    EMPRESAS_SUMINISTRADORAS_MANO_OBRA("Personal de edificios de Propiedad Horizontal",2),
    PERSONAL_EDIFICIOS_PROPIEDAD_HORIZONTAL("Informatica",3),
    INFORMATICA("Empresas suministradoras de mano de obra",22);


    private String texto;
    private double subGrupo;

    private TipoIndustria19SubGrupos(String texto, double subGrupo) {
        this.texto = texto;
        this.subGrupo = subGrupo;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return this.texto;
    }

    public double getSubGrupo() {
        return this.subGrupo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return texto;
    }
}
```

Third enum class

```
public enum TipoIndustria1SubGrupos {

    INDUSTRIA_LACTEA("Industria Láctea",1.1),
    DISTRIUBUIDORES_PRODUCTOS_LACTEOS("Distribuidores de Productos Lácteos",1.2),
    HELADERIAS_INDUSTRIALES("Heladerías industriales",1.3),
    EMPAQUE_ENVASADO_FRUTAS_LEGUMBRES("Empaque y envasado de frutas, legumbres y hortalizas",2),
    PRODUCCION_HIELO_CAMARAS_FRIO("Producción de hielo y cámaras de frío",3),
    INDUSTRIA_AZUCARERA("Industria azucarera",4),
    MOLINOS_ARROZ("Molinos de arroz",5),
    MOLINOS_DE_TRIGO_HARINAS_FECULAS("Molinos de trigo, harinas, féculas, sal y fábri", 6),
    MOLINOS_DE_TRIGO("Molinos de Trigo",6.1),
    FABRICA_RACIONES("Fábrica de raciones balanceadas",6.2),
    MOLINOS_DE_SAL("Molinos de sal",6.3),
    DULCES_CHOCOLATES_GOLOS("Dulces, chocolates, golosinas, galletitas y alf",7),
    DULCES_CHOCOLATES_GOLOS_GALL("Dulces, chocolates, golosinas, galletitas y alf",7.1),
    FIDEERIAS("Fideerías",7.2),
    PANIFICADORAS_INDUSTRIALES("Panificadoras Industriales",7.3),
    MOLINDOS_DE_YERBA("Molinos de Yerba",7.4),
    MOLINOS_DE_CAFE("Molinos de café y té",7.5),
    ACEITRAS_VEGETAL_ANIMAL("Aceiteras de origen animal o vegetal para uso h",8),
    ACEITERAS("Aceiteras",8.1),
    GRASAS_MARGARINAS("Grasas y margarinas",8.2),
    BEBIDAS_SIN_ALCOHOL_CERVEZAS("Bebidas sin alcohol y cervezas",9.1),
    MALTERIAS("Malterías",9.2),
    LICORERIAS("Licorerías",10),
    BODEGAS("Bodegas",11),
    FABRICACION_HELADOS_PANADERIAS_CON_PLANTA_ELABORACION("Fabricación de helados, panaderías y con plantas de elaboración",12),
    PANADERIAS_CONFITERIAS_PLANTA_DE_ELABORACION("Panaderías y confiterías con planta de elaboración",12.1),
    FABRICA_PASTAS("Fábricas de Pastas",12.2),
    CATERING_INDUSTRIAL("Catering industrial",12.3),
    TABACOS_CIGARRILLOS("Tabacos y cigarrillos",13),
    TABACOS_Y_CIGARRILLOS("Tabacos y cigarrillos",13.1),
    PLANTAS_DE_ACOPIO("Plantas de acopio y proc. de hojas de tabaco",13.2);





    private String texto;
    private double subGrupo;

    private TipoIndustria1SubGrupos(String texto, double subGrupo) {
        this.texto = texto;
        this.subGrupo = subGrupo;

    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return this.texto;
    }

    public double getSubGrupo() {
        return this.subGrupo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return texto;
    }

}
```

This is my WindowAplicattion Frame

```
public class VentanaEmpresa extends JInternalFrame implements IVentanaEmpresa {

    private TipoIndustria tipoIndustria;
    private TipoIndustria19SubGrupos tipoIndustria19;

    private JTextField txtRazonSocial;
    private JTextField txtDireccion;
    private JTextField txtLocalidad;
    private JTextField txtRuc;
    private JTextField txtLocal;

    private JLabel lblDatosGeneralesDe;
    private JLabel lblRazonSocial;
    private JLabel lblRuc;
    private JLabel lblDireccion;
    private JLabel lblTipoIndustria;
    private JLabel lblSubGrupo;
    private JLabel lblLocal;
    private JLabel lblLocalidad;

    private JComboBox comboSubGrupos;
    private ComboTipoIndustria comboTipoIndustria;
    private ComboTipoIndustria19SubGrupos comboSubGrupoTipoIndustria19;
    private ComboTipoIndustria1SubGrupos comboSubGrupoTipoIndustria1;

    private JButton btnGuardar;
    private JButton btnSalir;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    VentanaEmpresa frame = new VentanaEmpresa();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public VentanaEmpresa() {
        setTitle("EMPRESA");
        setBounds(100, 100, 772, 356);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        getContentPane().add(getLblDatos());
        getContentPane().add(getLblRazonSocial());
        getContentPane().add(getLblRazonSocial());
        getContentPane().add(getLblRuc());
        getContentPane().add(getLblDireccion());
        getContentPane().add(getLblTipoIndustria());
        getContentPane().add(getLblSubGrupo());
        getContentPane().add(getLblLocal());
        getContentPane().add(getLblLocalidad());

        getContentPane().add(getComboSubGrupos());
        getContentPane().add(getComboTipoIndustria());

        getContentPane().add(getTxtLocalidad());
        getContentPane().add(getTxtRazonSocial());
        getContentPane().add(getTxtDireccion());
        getContentPane().add(getTxtRuc());
        getContentPane().add(getTxtLocal());

        getContentPane().add(getBtnGuardar());
        getContentPane().add(getBtnSalir());

    }

    private JLabel getLblDatos() {
        if (lblDatosGeneralesDe == null) {
            lblDatosGeneralesDe = new JLabel("DATOS GENERALES DE LA EMPRESA");
            lblDatosGeneralesDe.setBounds(279, 11, 191, 21);
        }
        return lblDatosGeneralesDe;
    }

    private JLabel getLblRazonSocial() {
        if (lblRazonSocial == null) {
            lblRazonSocial = new JLabel("RAZON SOCIAL:");
            lblRazonSocial.setBounds(10, 58, 90, 21);

        }

        return lblRazonSocial;
    }

    private JLabel getLblRuc() {
        if (lblRuc == null) {
            lblRuc = new JLabel("RUC:");
            lblRuc.setBounds(400, 58, 70, 21);

        }

        return lblRuc;
    }

    private JLabel getLblDireccion() {
        if (lblDireccion == null) {
            lblDireccion = new JLabel("DIRECCION:");
            lblDireccion.setBounds(10, 159, 90, 21);

        }
        return lblDireccion;
    }

    private JLabel getLblTipoIndustria() {
        if (lblTipoIndustria == null) {
            lblTipoIndustria = new JLabel("TIPO INDUSTRIA:");
            lblTipoIndustria.setBounds(10, 211, 100, 21);

        }
        return lblTipoIndustria;
    }

    private ComboTipoIndustria getComboTipoIndustria() {
        if (comboTipoIndustria == null) {
            comboTipoIndustria = new ComboTipoIndustria();
            comboTipoIndustria.setBounds(120, 212, 223, 20);
        }
        return comboTipoIndustria;
    }

    private JComboBox getComboSubGrupos() {
        if (comboSubGrupos == null) {
            comboSubGrupos = new ComboTipoIndustria19SubGrupos();
            comboSubGrupos.setBounds(482, 211, 166, 21);
            comboSubGrupos.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                }
            });
        }
        return comboSubGrupos;
    }

    private JLabel getLblSubGrupo() {
        if (lblSubGrupo == null) {
            lblSubGrupo = new JLabel("SUBGRUPO:");
            lblSubGrupo.setBounds(400, 211, 70, 21);

        }
        return lblSubGrupo;
    }

    private JLabel getLblLocal() {
        if (lblLocal == null) {
            lblLocal = new JLabel("LOCAL:");
            lblLocal.setBounds(400, 113, 58, 21);

        }
        return lblLocal;
    }

    private JLabel getLblLocalidad() {
        if (lblLocalidad == null) {
            lblLocalidad = new JLabel("LOCALIDAD:");
            lblLocalidad.setBounds(10, 109, 90, 21);

        }
        return lblLocalidad;
    }

    private JTextField getTxtRazonSocial() {
        if (txtRazonSocial == null) {
            txtRazonSocial = new JTextField();
            txtRazonSocial.setBounds(120, 58, 223, 20);
            txtRazonSocial.setColumns(10);
        }
        return txtRazonSocial;
    }

    private JTextField getTxtDireccion() {
        if (txtDireccion == null) {
            txtDireccion = new JTextField();
            txtDireccion.setBounds(120, 159, 223, 20);
            txtDireccion.setColumns(10);
        }
        return txtDireccion;
    }

    private JTextField getTxtLocalidad() {
        if (txtLocalidad == null) {
            txtLocalidad = new JTextField();
            txtLocalidad.setBounds(120, 109, 223, 20);
            txtLocalidad.setColumns(10);
        }
        return txtLocalidad;
    }

    private JTextField getTxtRuc() {
        if (txtRuc == null) {
            txtRuc = new JTextField();
            txtRuc.setColumns(10);
            txtRuc.setBounds(480, 58, 223, 20);

        }
        return txtRuc;
    }

    private JTextField getTxtLocal() {
        if (txtLocal == null) {
            txtLocal = new JTextField();
            txtLocal.setColumns(10);
            txtLocal.setBounds(480, 113, 70, 20);

        }
        return txtLocal;
    }

    private JButton getBtnGuardar() {
        if (btnGuardar == null) {
            btnGuardar = new JButton("GUARDAR");
            btnGuardar.setBounds(254, 292, 89, 23);

        }
        return btnGuardar;
    }

    private JButton getBtnSalir() {
        if (btnSalir == null) {
            btnSalir = new JButton("SALIR");
            btnSalir.setBounds(400, 292, 89, 23);

        }
        return btnSalir;
    }

    // getters for IGUI

    public TipoIndustria getTipoIndustria() {
        return getComboTipoIndustria().getTipoIndustriaItemSeleccionado();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  ..

Comment: .. Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).